# Joules experiment: how to find the final temperature of the second compartment given just the initial and final temperature of first compartment

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

I have this problem I am trying to solve where we have a set up very similar to the one in Joule's experiment where he proved that the internal energy of an ideal gas depends only on its temperature. Here is the situation: we have two compartments of the same volume, thermodynamically isolated from the environment and between themselves. The walls of the system are not deformable. Compartment A has a certain pressure $P_{A1}$ and an initial temperature of 293 K. Compartment B is initially under perfect vacuum. A valve allows us to release some of the gas in compartment A to compartment B. We shut the valve after the pressures are equal and the final temperature of compartment A is 240 K, find the temperature of compartment B after the pressures are equalized.

To me it seems like there isn't enough information to actually find a numerical value but the next question asks me to explain why we get the value obtained. Here is my attempt at a solution:

First I used the equation of state:
$$P_{A2}V = P_{B2}V$$
$$\frac{n_{A2}RT_{A2}V}{n_{B2}RT_{B2}V} = 1$$
$$\Longrightarrow \frac{n_{A2}}{n_{B2}} = \frac{T_{B2}}{T_{A2}}$$

Since $n_{A1} = n_{B2} + n_{A2}$, we can write

$$\frac{n_{A2}}{n_{A1}-n_{A2}} = \frac{T_{B2}}{T_{A2}}$$

And that is where I am currently stuck. I know that the internal energy variation of the gas is zero but since we are working with 2 compartments I don't know what to do with this information. Also the initial temperature in compartment B is technically undefined from what I understand. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The gas in tank A at any point through the process has undergone an adiabatic reversible expansion, as it expands to push the gas ahead of it out the valve.  For this adiabatic reversible expansion, $$Pv^{\gamma}=C$$where v is the specific volume of the gas in tank A:  $$v=\frac{V}{n}$$where n is the tank volume (a constant).  So $$P\left(\frac{V}{n}\right)^{\gamma}=C$$Taking the natural log of this equation and then evaluating the differentials of both sides gives:  $$d\ln{P}-\gamma\ln{n}=0$$Aslo, from the ideal gas equation, we have:  $$d\ln{P}=d\ln{n}+d\ln{T}$$Combining these two equations gives$$(\gamma-1)d\ln{n}=d\ln{T}$$or$$\frac{n_2}{n_1}=\left(\frac{T_2}{T_1}\right)^{\frac{1}{(\gamma-1)}}$$This gives you the fraction of the initial number of moles in tank A that ends up in tank B.

The other equation that is needed is that the change in internal energy of the entire system is zero since no work has been done and no heat has been exchanged:  $$n_2C_v(240-293)+(n_1-n_2)C_v(T_B-293)=0$$$T_B$ will be higher than the initial temperature 293 K.